# Putting Pre-Prepared Food On An Already On Pilot on Shabbath

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul

If one prepares food prior to the sun going down on Erev Shabbath, and then puts it on a pilot that was on prior to the sun going down in order for the food to be warm, are they allowed to partake in that food on Shabbath?

Comment: A pilot light is usually not strong enough to warm food much. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @msh210 in reference to the stove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2793&PageIndex=57

Comment: A lot of variables.